# PDO или mysqli?

Tags: php_pdo, php, mysql

Да, я опять с этим)

Я решил перейти с mysql на другую технологию, либо PDO, либо mysqli.
Изменения типа БД совсем не планируется. Пока склоняюсь в сторону mysqli, т.к. там более привычный синтаксис.
По скорости, как я понял, mysqli превосходит mysql, но mysqli и PDO примерно равны.

Что посоветуете?

Comment: Только сегодня на [хабре][1] писали на тему PDO


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/php/137664/

Comment: @Dex, я читал эту статью, и после этого подумал об использовании PDO.
А потом подумал о mysqli)

Comment: Используйте PDO, сегодня вы работаете только с mysql, но кто знает может завтра вам прийдется работать с postgresql или mssql. Хорошо если код вашего проекта это несколько файлов, которые можно быстро переосмыслить под новые условия, а если нет ?

Comment: @uvlad +1! Но все же если проект был целенаправлен на то а не на это, нет смысла строить новый велосипед!

Comment: @uvlad, я же пишу: "Изменения типа БД совсем не планируется."

Comment: > По скорости, как я понял, mysqli
> превосходит mysql, но mysqli и PDO
> примерно равны.

А планируются оченьсильночерезвычайномногочисленные запросы к БД, или это просто очередная `Headache` дабы небыло скушно? Чисто спортивный интерес!

Comment: @Palmervan, что-то среднее. Ну в любом случае, как я понял, советуют mysql уже не использовать. Легче всего мне перейти на mysqli - меньше придётся изменить.
На PDO - придётся больше менять, поэтому и хочу узнать, есть ли смысл выбрать PDO, а не mysqli.

Comment: @Palmervan, все зависит от условий и как они часто меняются... могу сказать на своём примере, в учреждение по месту работы используется несколько баз данных (mysql,postgresql,mssql) каждая под свои нужды и свои проекты, хотя ограничений по использованию нету, просто мне привычней работать с mysql. Но вот и делал я не большой проект с mysql, но только закончил как условия поменялись и появились новые требования в которых без использования mssql не обойтись. Хорошо использовал PDO, менять пришлось не много, только то что не поддерживалось драйвером.

Comment: @uvlad, хорошо, может я буду использовать PDO, если даже БД не будет меняться, то для опыта. PDO ведь не медленней mysqli точно.
Вроде там ещё что-то есть по поводу более хорошей безопасности в PDO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PDO, в разы гибче. Даже сравнивать не хочу с mysqli. Достаточно посмотреть описание на php.net чтобы в этом убедиться самому.